# Anyone leaving the Nether exits through my house?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The SMP server I play on just updated to Minecraft 1.6.6. We were all really excited about the Nether.

However no matter how many portals we make, when you leave the Nether and comeback to the real world, you end my house (my safe of all places). These portals are not close to each other, but they still connect.

It has become so common for people to exit through my house that I had to give directions.

[image]

How can we fix this?

Comment: Does it run Bukkit or is it a vanilla install? If Bukkit, which build # is it running?

Comment: @Thomas: It does run Bukkit, I'm not sure what build. I'll check with my admin.

Comment: @LucasMcCoy: Okay, 'tis just that recommended build #860 was released yesterday which 'improved nether portal handling'

Comment: @Thomas: It runs `Craftbukkit version git-Bukkit-0.0.0-823-gb9d0b04-b860jnks (MC: 1.66)` if that makes any sense.

Comment: @Thomas: Ok I'll let my admin know and see if that helps.

Comment: @Thomas: We just updated and were still having the same problem.

Comment: How close is "not close to each other"?

Comment: @Mark: Well I have a portal at my house and my closet neighbor has one also. He's about 1000 blocks away. Is that too close? :)

Comment: @Lucas How close are the portals in the nether?

Comment: There is only 1 portal in the Nether that we enter through. All the portals we make on the surface are linked to it. If we make a new portal in the nether, it still exits at my house.

Comment: @Lucas Right, how close is that new portal to the existing portal?

Comment: git-Bukkit-0.0.0-823-gb9d0b04-b860jnks is Build #860.

Comment: @Mark: I don't think I understand what your asking, but the closet portals are about 1000 blocks apart.

Comment: @Lucas So the portals in the real world are 1,000 meters away, and you have one portal in the Nether. The second portal you make in the Nether (the one that exits at your house) is also 1,000 meters away from the first one? The divide-by-8 length contraction of the Nether usually means people build portals way closer than the distance they want to travel in the real world, so that's why I'm trying to confirm that 1,000 meters applies to both realms.

Comment: You can fix that easy. It's "you're", not "your".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you need to take the time to properly align the portals in both worlds.  It takes some effort, but if you exactly align your portals everything seems to work correctly on the SMP server I regularly play on.

From the [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Portal#Linkage_between_Overworld_and_Nether).

> To setup pairs of portals properly so
> that they reliably travel to each
> other, it is best to build both
> portals manually. Build at desired
> location X,Y,Z in the Normal World.
> Then travel to the Nether World. And
> then dig your way to X/8, Y, Z/8, and
> build a portal there.